# Does any state or settings remain after an app uninstall?

Tags: crashes, instagram

So on my primary phone, a few weeks ago, whenever I opened up instagram it crashed.  I thought my life would be better without it, and I have multiple devices so I uninstalled it.

A few weeks later, I installed it again and it immediately crashed every time.

I did a data integrity spot check of the SD card and it passed (essentially I wrote at different sectors, ran some checksums ... did a few things to convince myself that the storage system wasn't bad) so we can eliminate that.

All the other parts of the phone are "functional". Other apps don't crash and all the hardware seems to be operational.

The only thing that I can conclude is that the uninstall left something sitting around that a subsequent install is trying to use.

I can't do strace, lsof, or gdb on this thing. So here's a few ways to solve this problem, any being acceptable:

- Have you seen this before and is there some place you can link me to to learn more about it?
- Are there (this is just yes or no, I just thought of this now) ways to step through app-store apks that are running through say android studio, looking at things like open file handles, or the raised exceptions (beyond what adb logcat tells you of course) - or are there ways to generate a core file that can be analyzed out of band?
- Is there some other storage subsystem, such as an SQLite3 database somewhere, where such settings often linger, that I can check?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/158509/86358

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes files on the SDCards remain. Especially watch for `Android/data/<package_name>` and `data/<package_name>` directories, as well as top-level directories which seem to belong to the app.